Running scheduled Calculate accrual balances up to end of the year
I have some payroll formulas which use the absence plan net entitlement at the end of each year to run some calculations. I can get this value from the UI from the absence records page by changing the balance calculation date.
However this has proven impossible to retrieve in my payroll fast formula. I tried formula functions like GET_NET_ACCRUAL, GET_PLAN_BALANCE etc to get the absence plan accrual in the future but none of these ever seem to work.
I have now decided to run accruals up until the end of the year. My question is, how do I setup a scheduled process to run the
Calculate Accruals and Balances
process up until the end of the current year on a daily basis. My absence plan accrual increments every month.

Can you please give us some sample data and expected output.
